# If I run two monitors from two different graphic cards, can I still have Twinview?

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, twinview

I am planning to get a second 2560x1440 monitor for home. The trouble is, I only have 1xDVI, 1xVGA on my graphics card (a 250 GT). I don't want to buy a new graphics card until the prices for the 500 series have stabilized, so probably not before summer (or will it happen earlier? I don't remember how it was for other series, and I couldn't find long-term price history for video cards).

The solution I had in mind is to get the 7600 GS from my old PC, which also has 1xDVI, 1xVGA, and run each monitor on a separate card. I have never done that, and I was wondering 1. If I will be able to run the monitors in Twinview then, or will I be stuck with separate X sessions, and 2. Whether there are some other disadvantages as compared to a single-head graphics card. (I am using the proprietary driver because I need compiz).

As an aside, how do I find out whether the DVI port on the old graphics card is dual link?

Comment: 7600GS is almost certainly dual-link DVI; I know that from having had tons of them.  (The easiest way to tell is just to look it up, it IS possible you have a specific SKU that isn't - there's not any readily apparent visible difference unless you want to count solder points)

Comment: And what's wrong with normal extended desktop anyway?  I don't think Twinview is even supported anymore.

Comment: What do you understand under "normal extended desktop", maybe this is a nouveau option? I am using the current proprietary nVidia driver, and all it offers is Twinview or separate X sessions.